# Powershell and par2 command line

Tags: backup, powershell

I have a working script which 7zips sql bak files to a network location (helped by the good people here:)). since 7zip doesn't have recovery records i would like to use par2. now, i have put together a script which (i'm not surprised, because i really don't know powershell) doesn't work.

Script:

```
$path = "\\server\BACKUP\temp"

$dest = $path

$mask = "*.zip"

$files = dir $path -Include $mask

foreach ($file in $files)

{

C:\PAR\par2.exe c -r10 -n1 -m1024 "$dest\($file.basename).par2" $file

}
```

i think i'm not far off but the solution escapes me :(

ty in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of how par2.exe function so I assuming all args you plugin to the par2.exe are valid. I commented out the last line with a "#", which  is supposed to execute the command. Please run the script first to verify that the print output is what exactly you need to run, then remove the starting "#" from last line to execute the command.

```
$path = "\\server\BACKUP\temp"

$dest = $path

$mask = "*.zip"

$files = get-childitem $path | where-object {$_.name -like $mask} 

$PARCMD = "C:\PAR\par2.exe"

foreach ($file in $files)

{
    $arg = $dest + "\" + $file.name + ".par2"
    $PARArgs = @("c","-r10","-n1","-m1024",$arg,$file)
    write-host $PARCMD $PARArgs
    #& $PARCMD $PARArgs
 }
```

I'm using powershell 4.0 but I do think this should be back compatible with 2.0/3.0, please post error here if you get any, I will help out.

Comment: Ty very much. That's it. Just had to modify it a bit (had to give full path). This is the final product: `remove-psdrive -name s new-psdrive -name S -PsProvider FileSystem -root \\server\BACKUP\temp -persist $path = "S:" $dest = "S:\RecoveryRecords" $mask = "*.zip" $files = get-childitem $path | where-object {$_.name -like $mask} $PARCMD = "C:\PAR\par2.exe" foreach ($file in $files) { $arg = $dest + "\" + $file.name + ".par2" $file = $path + "\" + $file.name $PARArgs = @("c","-r10","-n1","-m1024",$arg,$file) write-host $PARCMD $PARArgs & $PARCMD $PARArgs }` Ty, again :)